# Two angularjs factory, same data

Tags: angularjs, factory

I have two js files, i need to retreive a particular data (for compare), so i do it with a factory :

```
factory :
app.factory('DistantFactory', function($http, $q) {

    var factoryD = {
        distant : false,
        getDistant : function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDataDistant, cache: false, timeout: 1500}).
                success(function(data, status) {

                    var dataD = paramsField.params[0].data.date;

                    /* define data */
                    factoryD.distant = dataD;
                    deferred.resolve(factoryD.distant);


                }).error(function(data, statuts) {
                    deferred.reject('ERROR');
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    // return
    return factoryD;
});






app.factory('LocalFactory', function($http, $q) {

    var factory = {
        local : false,
        getLocal : function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDataLocalIntern, cache: false, timeout: 1500}).
                success(function(data, status) {

                    var dataL = paramsField.params[0].data.date;

                    /* define data */
                    factory.local = dataL;
                    deferred.resolve(factory.local);

                }).error(function(data, statuts) {
                    deferred.reject('ERROR');
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    // return
    return factory;
});
```

in controller:

```
                $scope.dataD = DistantFactory.getDistant().then(function(distant) {

                    $scope.dataD = distant;
                    $scope.dataL = LocalFactory.getLocal().then(function(local) {
                        $scope.dataL = local;

                        var dataD = distant;
                        var dataL = local;

(...)
```

dataD have a problem: it's same value as dataL. In files, there is no same value, so, what's wrong ?

Comment: based on your question i think you need to separate two controllers? looks like they all jam into one

Comment: but how to compare the two data and send it to the view (true/false result) ?

Comment: `distant == local`? And why are you assigning a value to dataD and dataL 3 times? The one inside `then` is enough.

Comment: this is a test, i don't know if values are same or not, my code is a test

Comment: Any chance you can create this in jsfiddle or plunker with a minimal set of data for each, so we can easily see what's not working?

Comment: but now, there is a problem, values are not supposed to be same, but angularjs see that is same value, so i have a problem with the controller

Answer (score 1):

Something with your data is wrong. I've cleaned up and recreated your app in Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/j0RYPKbLPkk1mErVow73?p=preview) and, as you see, it works perfectly fine with the fake data I'm using.

Without more info about the actual data, we can't help you.

---

UPDATE

You're fetching .js files, but not evaluating them (not sure how are you seeing the values since it has to throw an error). That's why the variables from those files are not available in your script. One way to do it, but I don't recommend it is to `eval()` the returned data, but it's **very dangerous** (security-wise)! See the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4UqrwRzl7RHcTNbuOGZ6?p=preview

What I would suggest is to return the JSON instead. $http will automatically recognize it and your object will be available as `data.params[0].data.date`. See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mFfrcJYIJiv6yLkOsM7J?p=preview

Comment: I updated the code : http://plnkr.co/edit/0YtwyWUawDVgaYHywZin when i run my app, it's show me an old value. check the distants files, values are not the same, so i don't understand...

Comment: result in console : "2014-05-07 / 2014-05-07" Check the distant files, it's not the values...

Comment: How are you getting that? I'm getting an error: `paramsField is not defined`... which makes perfect sense because you're not executing the js code... I'll update my answer and show you why.